# error en indice de cadena en java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Estoy leyendo una pagina y extrayendo partes que me interesan a partir de un `indexof` para indicarle donde comenzar cortando lineas para agregarlas a un array y que se guarde en un archivo. 
 Me funciona, el problema es que no me funciona en todas la paginas, en varias me da un error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -59567

Dejo el codigo para ver si pueden ayudarme. Aclaro que todas las paginas son practicamente iguales y contienen la misma palabra indice.

```
try {

        URL url = new URL("https://webx.com");
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

        BufferedInputStream buffer = new 
        BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int byteRead;
        while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1) {
            builder.append((char) byteRead);
        }

        buffer.close();

                FileWriter fichero = null;
                PrintWriter pw = null;

        System.out.println(builder.toString());
        String webdescargada = "";
        webdescargada = (builder.toString());
        System.out.println("The size of the web page is " + builder.length() + " bytes.");

        int inicio = (webdescargada.indexOf("\"listingLightweight\">")+20);
        int fin = (webdescargada.indexOf("</ol> <div", inicio + 1) + 

        String webrecortada = "";
        webrecortada = (webdescargada.substring(inicio + 1, fin));

        String[] arraydeliclass = webrecortada.split("</div></li>");

        for (int i = 0; i < arraydeliclass.length; i++) {


        }

        try
    {
        fichero = new FileWriter("archivo.txt",true);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            pw.println(arraydeliclass[i]);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       try {

       if (null != fichero)
          fichero.close();
       } catch (Exception e2) {
          e2.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Starts the program
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Amiscrap3().getWebSite();
```

Gracias de antemano por leer.

Comment: Deberías indicar DÓNDE te lanza el error. En todo caso el error es que te está intentando encontrar la posición - 59567 al operar con un String, así que el problema está al calcular alguno de los índices que usas para operar con String.

Comment: no no busca la posicion -59567, lo que pasa es que indexof recibe un string y con ese string busca la posicion en un array pero no lo esta encontrando

Comment: Gracias a los 2 por responder.
 el numero del error cambia, es decir que primero me tira el error en -59567, y despues lo vuelvo a intentar (sin hacer ninguna modificacion) y el error arroja el numero -59525, y si vuelvo a intentar cambia.

Comment: seguro que existe esta "\"listingLightweight\">")+20 en tu cadena??

Comment: No!!!, no existe. tenia un caracter de mas para la proxima busqueda y por eso no lo encontraba.Gracias por la ayuda.
 Hace poco que estoy en programacion y cada error son horas de intentos, lectura de foros y demas. Lo bueno es que aprendo mas que en clases. Gracias otra vez Igmer y SJuan